# Mysql query not working with join if one query is fetching no data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to find total inventory and available inventory from below mentioned table.
Table Structure:

```
[Inventoryid] [inventory Type ] [issue status]
1              Mobile            Issued
2              Tablet            Not Issued
3              Mobile            Issued
4              Tablet            Not Issued
```

The outpot required is

```
[Inventory Type] [Total Inventory]  [Available Inventory]
Mobile            2                  0
Tablet            2                  2
```

Please give me the query for the same.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT  inventoryType,
        COUNT(*) totalInventory,
        SUM(issuestatus = 'not issued') available
FROM    tableName
GROUP   BY inventoryType
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7f5bb/2)

Answer (score 1):

```
select inventory_type , count(*), sum(case when issue_Status = 'not issued' then 1
else 0 end) as status
From yourtable
group by inventory_type
;
```

Comment: This is more portable than the other answer, although you've mixed it up: it should be `when issue_Status = 'not issued' then 1 else 0`.

Comment: @AndriyM oh shoot..thanks missed that out.. this will work in RDBMS like Oracle as well :) where `Sum(boolean)` will not work..

Comment: @AndriyM yes, it's `MySQL` specific. but then the question was *firstly* tag with `MySQL` not with `SQL` only.

Comment: @JW.: You are perfectly right, this is a MySQL question, and I have no issues about your using MySQL-specific features in your answer. :) It was merely a matter of pointing out merits where it was due. This answer is more portable, while yours is shorter. Both have now received recognition. :)

Comment: @AndriyM I haven't any issues either `:D` I just want to show some features in mysql but not on the others. `:)`